# Select penultimate sms received

Tags: android

I have an application in Android that aims to obtain penultimate message received, but I do not find the way. I have the following code:

```
    ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);

    int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( ReceptorSMS.BODY );
    int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( ReceptorSMS.ADDRESS );

    if ( cursor.moveToLast())return;

       smsList.clear();




    do
    {
       str = "Sender: " + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" + cursor.getString( indexBody );



    }
     while( cursor.moveToPrevious());
    Toast.makeText( this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Out of curiousity, why the _penultimate_ (second-to-most-recent) message?  What's wrong with the simple most-recent SMS?  I'm not sure you can completely guarantee the order you receive messages in, so if you're attempting something with multiple messages you may be out of luck.

Comment: I need to know the second last message received.

Comment: Which is **really strange**.  The only thing this would do is delay processing by some non-deterministic amount (when you receive the next SMS).  There's no guarantee that a new message will ever even show up!  For that matter, depending on what other apps may be scraping/maintaining messages, you don't have any guarantee that new messages would be retained there anyways.  What problem are you trying to solve that you think you need the second-to-last message?  Personally I'd have classed this requirement as "impractical", "not sustainable", or "prone to various issues".